# Is there a straightforward way to create a symbology by multiple variables in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm currently working on a project based on election data, where I want to show both the winner and the majority for various boundaries with these being stored as attributes. The image below is the effect I'm going for - it's a hybrid of a categorised style (to show the winner) and a graduated style (to show the percentage majority - with the colour ramp decided based on which party won).

[image: a majority shaded election map of the UK, with different colours representing the parties and different levels of shading representing how close the result was]

So far I have tried two approaches to create this effect - first I used rule based symbology and "Add Ranges to Category", but found this was too difficult to customise, and things like changing the colours used for a party or adjusting the symbols used for constituencies was a massive pain. Another approach was to create a field that combined the winner and the majority ("Winner"||round(Majority*20,0)) and to use a categorised style based on that, but I couldn't really get the graduated effect I was after - I had to set the colours manually myself. Obviously both of these methods work but they seem rather tedious and I was wondering if anyone knew of a more straightforward alternative?

Comment: sounds like you are trying to reinvent the bivariate choropleth map - see https://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=bivariate+%5Bqgis%5D

Comment: I think that's close to what I'm after (and I might be able to adapt the solutions there into something workable) but not quite the same - instead of having two colour ramps intersecting to represent different levels of two variables, I'm wanting to use various colour ramps to represent different levels of one variable, with the ramp used based on a different variable, if that makes sense?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do (if I understand correctly) will work, an alternative is to use opacity or size for the size of the majority.